# App is shutting down when Maps isn't installed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, maps

When i click on an link for Maps, my app is closing because no maps application is installed. How can i give an alert at the start of the app, that they can't use the Maps with no Maps application installed.

Thanks,

Comment: post your code and i'll tell you what to do?

Comment: My code isn't needed.. Ill need an script that makes an alert at the startup off the app when no Maps app is installed.

Comment: clueless.. give a brief explanation. Here map application indicates google maps or what?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create one method like this

```
public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage,
                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then check by this

```
if (isPackageExisted("com.google.android.maps")) {
    // Map application is available
 } else {
    // Map application is not available
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i click on an link for Maps. My app is closing because no maps application is installed.

If this "link" is triggering an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, perhaps on a `geo` `Uri`, create that `Intent` and use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()` to see if something on the device will handle it. If `resolveActivity()` returns `null`, you know that `startActivity()` for that `Intent` will crash, so you can take appropriate steps.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(isGoogleMapsInstalled){
//do your job
}else{
//display toast or whatever you want
}

public boolean isGoogleMapsInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );
        return true;
    } 
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How doing this when only if(isGoogleMapsNotInstalled) 
// display toast

Comment: Toast bread = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Install Google maps app...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
bread.show();finish();